# Extract files and rename specific file with specific extension using 7zip?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, zip, 7zip

I would like to use 7ZIP to extract files with specific extensions only, and then rename one of them accordingly.

Also, i must do this using a batch script (.bat) - No powershell or other methods.

I currently set up the following script, on a bat file:

```
@echo off
REM Force UTF-8 to fix some output problems
chcp 65001 > nul

REM Six columns, space delimited
for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %%A in ('"C:\Tools\7za.exe" l VPN.zip -ba -r *\*.ovpn') do (
    "C:\Tools\7za.exe" e VPN.zip -ba -r %%A > Test.ovpn
)

PAUSE
```

Output:

> It exracts two files.
>
> One is the archive itself (Archive...ovpn)
> The second one is the one i renamed (Test.ovpn)
> The second archive, instead of being the actual renamed archive, contains 7Zip logs...
> Log is below.

```
Processing archive: VPN.zip

Extracting  folder_name\Original_archive.ovpn

Everything is Ok

Size:       411 Compressed: 5800
```

It lists the files in my zipped archive...

What i want to achieve is:

> Extract files only to a folder called "VPN", and not folder_name.
>
> If the files contains the extension .ovpn, rename that file to "Test.ovpn"

I am very sorry if this question seems silly.
I am quite new on batch scripting field and here is the only place where i can get some help...

Thank you for anyone that helps me.

Edit: I updated the questions with the codes i'm using, since on comments they said this question was'nt clear enough...

Comment: Your question(s) have nothing whatsoever to do with an issue with yourr submitted code. What you are asking for is already available by reading the help information/man pages. `7za.exe -?` should at least show you its available options, and all of those are expanded upon within their [online documentation](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/index4.htm). You can also, should you wish to, take a look at the output from `if /?` and `rename /?` to learn how those commands work. This site is not here to write code for you to order, and it is not our job to summarize that research information for you.

Comment: What do yo want to happen if there is more than one subdirectory (folder_name) in the archive? Do you already know the value of 'folder_name'?

Comment: @Compo I already did look into documentation, but i couldnt do it. All my codes returned errors...

Comment: Yes @lit, i do have the value of folder_name.

Comment: So we need you to post the code you used, and those errors, we cannot help you to fix code without you submitting it, and showing us what happens when you run it. Please see [mcve].

Comment: Done. I updated my answer and now it contains exactly the code i'm trying to do what is the title of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the following code:

```
REM Extract files in archive
for %%f in (VPN.zip) do (

"C:\Tools\7za.exe" e "%%f" -ba -y -so -r *\*.ovpn 1>C:\VPN\VPN.ovpn 2>nul
"C:\Tools\7za.exe" e "%%f" -ba -y -r *\*.p12 -oC:\VPN >nul
"C:\Tools\7za.exe" e "%%f" -ba -y -r *\*.key -oC:\VPN >nul

) >nul
```